# DocuSign: Senders Complete-email always in english when using custom email-resource-file

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question/bug according docusign. 
When I use a custom email resource file, the completed-email to the sender is in english (instead of german as defined in the senders administration). Other emails to the sender are still in german (e.g. Signer viewed envelope etc...)
When I use a brand without resource file, the completed-email is in german as expected.

Does anyone has the same problem or a solution? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Please update Brand -> Email Resource File, and update the delta change to the node (`<data name="SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody">`) which you are interested and upload just the delta changed xml.

If you want to customize the resource file text for German (de), you would set up the resource file as follows:

```
<language twoletterisoname=”de”>
   [specific settings for German]
</language>
```

Please find the below link for guide to change email resource file

https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf